# 500 Internal Server error in pastie.el

Tags: emacs, elisp, pastie

Im using the pastie.el file located at http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/pastie.el. This is supposed to help us post code to pastie.org directly from emacs.
If the file im pasting contains "<" symbol then i get a 500 Internal Server Error message in emacs,because of which im unable to post ruby files, php files etc. 
Any way to fix this in the elisp file ?

Thank You

Comment: The regex in the function `pastie-region` seems like the culprit. Try it interactively on your code to see its results and adjust it to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I found a version at https://bitbucket.org/sid0/.emacs/raw/837539ad28ca/elisp-files/pastie.el which is working. Looking at the file i see that there was a problem with xml escaping for example instead of < we need to have &lt;

Comment: Just post this as an answer to your own question and accept it. It will be helpful to others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with xml escaping in the pastie.el located on emacswiki.org. I found a working version at https://bitbucket.org/sid0/.emacs/raw/837539ad28ca/elisp-files/pastie.el .